# How to host a Spring-Boot Application with MySql Backend online for free?

Tags: heroku, spring-boot

I have created a working spring-boot-app, which works flawless on my laptop. I wish to host it online.
To do so, I referred to many guides including pivotal, heroku. 
On Heroku, It says application error. 
I followed this link as walk-through: `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku`

Application log:`https://pastebin.com/nivpqEiJ`

I am an absolute beginner, please guide me how do I host it. Basically I applied in a company and they want me to host it so that they can test my application.

I feel maybe, its with application.properties. As I have mentioned my MySql credentials. But I don't know how to rectify this problem.
for reference,
here is the link to project on github: `https://github.com/pranavpsinha/SMS`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I tried heroku a while back and ran into similar problems, I sloved it by including a `Procfile` in my root with the following content: `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/sms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I've set my application to a web app in heroku.

You can find more info at [devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: I am using Spring-Tool-Suite. Where should i make changes?

Comment: Just add a file with the name Procfile to the root of your project, u can use the same content a I did. If your application builds a jar file  use `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/sms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` on the first line in the file. good luck